# How to find files which contain given fragment?

Tags: git, fzf

FZF (fuzzy finder) is very convenient to find files by filename. However, I sometimes only know a function name or a part of the name. Is there a way to get FZF-like search, which would filter files by their content? `git grep <pattern>` command line command provides the functionality I want, but it works outside VIM.

Is there a way to get `git grep` search results inside VIM? It would be better to get real-time results like in FZF, when I type letters - the suggested file names change.

Comment: [fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) provides a `:Rg` command, I think this is what you are looking for. It uses rigrep. Check the link for setup suggestions.

Comment: @Biggybi Wow, thats just great! Thats exactly what I was looking for :) Post this comment as an answer and will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) provides several commands suited for this task:

- `:Rg` which uses `ripgrep`
- `:Ag` which uses the Silver Searcher (`ag`)

These are external tools, they must be installed on the system (e.g. install `ripgrep` on a Debian based system:)

```
sudo apt install ripgrep
```

It is also possible to use `fzf` as a wrapper for `gitgrep`.
The link above provides a `Ggrep` command to do so:

```
command! -bang -nargs=* GGrep
  \ call fzf#vim#grep(
  \   'git grep --line-number -- '.shellescape(<q-args>), 0,
  \   fzf#vim#with_preview({'dir': systemlist('git rev-parse --show-toplevel')[0]}), <bang>0)
```

Read more at `:h fzf-vim`.
A list of fzf vim commands can be found under `:h fzf-vim-commands`.